# Wordpress: add slug in front of posts and remove the slugs from my CPT

Tags: wordpress

1. I created some CPTs with ACF Pro. Books and Movies.
   I want those to be removed from my url.
   So instead of mydomain.com/books/my-book1, I want this custom post type URL to be mydomain.com/my-book1.
2. And I also want my posts to have 'blog' in their url.
   So instead of mydomain.com/my-first-post, I want the url to be mydomain.com/blog/my-first-post.
   My blog listing page can already be found at mydomain.com/blog/

For 1), I use the `post_type_link` and the `pre_get_posts` hooks like seen on many posts. Ex: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/203951/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type-post-urls#answer-204210.

For 2), I changed my permalink settings to be `/blog/%postname%/`

Both solutions work on their own but not when they are implemented together.
If implemented together, I can reach the posts at mydomain.com/blog/my-first-post but the urls to the book CPT give a 404 (both mydomain.com/books/my-book1 and mydomain.com/my-book1).

I do not want to use another plugin for this but rather use another hook, or tweak the permalink settings or the CPT created in ACF Pro.

I have been struggling with this implementation for a few days now.
Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the post type slugs works if you set the ACF CPT **Permalink Rewrite** field to `Custom Permalink` and the **URL Slug** field to `/`

You can do that under ACF > Post Types > {post_type} > Advanced settings > URLs

Comment: Kevin Marsden, thx for the reply but your solution doesn't work in my use case.
As soon as I had `/blog/%postname%` to my Custom permalink structure, I lose (404) a CPT with you Permalink Rewrite solution.
With your permalink rewrite solution, I lose the /author/author_name url (404).
With your permalink rewrite and the cusomt permalink structure with the prefix `blog`, I also lose other pages (/about, ...).
I tried your settings on my site as well as on a fresh install.

Comment: Nathan, I'm also seeing strange rewrite behavior on some pages. I'll let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: Kevin :) If we use your solution on one CPT, we lose some pages like the `/author/AuthotName`. If you use it on 2 CPTs, you lose 1 CPT and the other one is working fine.
I've seen on other threads that your solution wasn't recommended but i do not remember why.
Right now, I know when I xdebug into the `pre_get_posts` hook, I already have a 404 and the `post_type_link` hook is not even fired, which is weird..
Maybe that's just a question of using a different hook or of a hook priority, I don't know.
But I can't believe this is not a more common use case and I didn't found a solution online!

Comment: Kevin, I know that developers do not use all Wordpress features when they develop a website (CPT, author page, custom permastructures, ..) but I plan to use a lot of them for a SEO and performance optimized one. Even using WPML in 25 different languages and I have nearly 20000 pages already. So I'm open to any advice and test any solutoins that could help me achieve my needs :)
The site is hardly a third of what it could be but waiting to fix those urls issues before to go further!